# How to add control to a panel during runtime?

Tags: c#, panel, windows-forms-designer

I want to add some buttons during run time to a existing panel in my form so that I can scroll them by my panel when the number of the buttons increases and they do not fit the form.

I use the `this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button50[number]);` but it does not show the button on the panel
How can I show the control on the panel after adding it?

Here is my code:

```
static int number = 49;
static int size = 163;
public void initialize()
{
    this.button50= new System.Windows.Forms.Button[50];

}
public void makeButton()
{
    if (number > 0)
    {
        this.button50[number] = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button50[number].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Nazanin"
        ,12F,System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, 
        System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(178)));

        size = 41 + size;
        this.button50[number].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(194, size);
        this.button50[number].Name = "buttonPlus"+number;
        this.button50[number].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(151, 34);
        this.button50[number].TabIndex = 24;
        this.button50[number].Text = "انتخاب دستی دروس";
        this.button50[number].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button50[number]);

        number--;
    }

}
    //// a part of InitializeComponent() function
    //
    // panel1
    //
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button50[number]);
    this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button10);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button3);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button8);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button9);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button5);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button7);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button6);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button4);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button2);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.bindingNavigator1);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.lable4);
    this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
    this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(549, 306);
    this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
```

Comment: check your `button7`'s location to make sure it doesn't locate out of `panel1` view port

Comment: the button that I add does not exceed the form and panels dimension but still it does not show my button on the panel I had no problem adding the button one the form itself.

Comment: is that Button 7 (all the controls in initialization ) is added by you manually isn't it ..!!

Comment: no the new buttons created in the 'makebutton()' function are not shown when they are added.
the other buttons are shown.

Comment: Several visible flaws.  Use BringToFront() so the button can't be overlapped by another control.  You probably want to call Focus() so the panel scrolls the button into view.  You must adjust the button's Location by adding the panel's AutoScrollPosition.  Do **not** edit designer generated code.

Comment: @HansPassant I think edit designer generated code is not a bad idea as long as you know what you're doing